# How to get value from database and display it in MInecraft Client for cosmetics

Tags: java, mysql, minecraft

I am coding a Minecraft PvP Client and I want to make online cosmetics but I don't know how to get values from my database so the Client can render the cosmetics for the player. Can somebody help? Btw I have a mysql database.

Comment: You want to login to your DB from the client ? So give password to your DB to everyone ?